# MBXMapKit using local .mbtiles database file

Tags: mapkit, mapbox

I would like to use MapKit (on osx) to display custom map tiles from a .mbtiles (sqlite) database of the sort exported from TileMill.

[MBXMapKit](https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit) looks great, and is *almost* what I'm looking for. I could see how, with very little modification, MBXMapKit could be tweaked to point to a local .mbtiles database file.

Is there any way to use the MBXMapKit framework to accomplish this without tweaking? I did read the docs, and couldn't find a straightforward answer. I did find a private method on `MBXOfflineMapDatabase` called `-initWithContentsOfFile:` which sounds promising and looks like it does what I need -- is there anything to watch out for if I expose and use that method?

Alternate option is to subclass `MKTileOverlay` and use `-loadTileAtPath:result:`, which is easy to do, but also requires managing the connection to the sqlite file etc.

Comment: quick followup: looks like MBXMapKit's local sqlite cache is a completely different schema than .mbtiles -- which is too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this for the latest on MBTiles support:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/issues/3

It'll be coming probably in the next release. This should be distinct and separate from both the normal performance cache (`NSURLCache`) as well as the (also SQLite-backed) offline databases, which are meant for individual tile downloads being placed into a cache one-by-one.

Comment: ok, so not yet but soon. turns out it's pretty easy to do the db stuff with FMDB database pool and it's reasonably fast. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite some time to work this out, but here is the link that got me on the right path.

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/pull/110/commits/8b9fbf3fd56ae804a38c737305f128fd43a8225d

For some reason the method `_mbtilesOverlay = [[MBXMBTilesOverlay alloc] initWithMBTilesURL:mbtilesURL];` can not be used on the latest version of MBXMapKit. I just replaced the .m and .h files with the files in the link, and used `MBXViewController.m` as a guide to get the map view to show the tile overlay.